# Python, encoding issues when converting XLSX to CSV

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, xlsx

```
   name  street city
    엄니밥상    영등포동2가  서울특별시
    우리은행광희동지점입구 광희동1가   서울특별시
```

I am trying to convert to it CSV but I either get question marks instead of Korean characters in the output file or partially incorrect characters consolidated in one cell if I use UTF-16

The code I use is quite simple:

```
 data_xls = pd.read_excel('tel.xlsx',  'Sheet1', index_col=None)
 data_xls.to_csv('tel.csv', encoding='utf_16',na_rep='NA',index=False)
```

The results I get:
UTF-16 (columns consolidated in one column):

```
name,street,city਍쐀죅▲솼ⳀĀ�㊳Ⲭᰀ룁맆쓒�ෂ
우리은행광희동지점입구,광희동1가,서울특별시਍
```

UTF-8:

```
name    street  city
ì—„ë‹ˆë°¥ìƒ    ì˜ë“±í¬ë™2ê°€    ì„œìš¸íŠ¹ë³„ì‹œ
ìš°ë¦¬ì€í–‰ê´‘í¬ë™ì§€ì ìž…êµ¬   ê´‘í¬ë™1ê°€   ì„œìš¸íŠ¹ë³„ì‹œ
```

Comment: What is the encoding of the `.xlsx` file ? Are you using Python 2 or 3 ?

Comment: The XLSX is UTF-8 and I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Have you tried using `pd.read_excel('tel.xlsx',  'Sheet1', index_col=None, encoding='utf_8')` ? (I think the CSV is being read as ISO-8859-* and written as UTF-*)

Comment: Yes, I did try it, it has no effect on the output

Comment: Are you sure your input file is properly UTF-8 ? I reconstructed an UTF-8 `.xlsx` from the data you pasted, and using your code with encoding properly both on `read_excel` and `to_csv`, I had correct output using either UTF-8 or UTF-16 output.

Comment: It is UTF-8. Not sure why it does not show it correctly for me then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119012/discussion-between-pistache-and-evgeni).